# the "com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup" error in implementing drawer

Tags: android, xml, drawer

I'm trying to implement a drawer in android but i get this error: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
I searched too much and addressed any problems about the android.support.v4 jar file but it still has the error.
here is my xml code:

```
     <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
     >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"        
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            >

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/et_tv1"
                android:background="@color/lgrey"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                />
            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/et_tv2"
                android:background="@color/lgrey"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et_tv1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/Drawer"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:background="@color/azure4"
     />   
            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/capture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="submit"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
           <Button 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="timesheet"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="apply"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You need to close the `<LinearLayout>` tag after everything you want in the drawer, instead of self-closing the opening tag.

Comment: thank you, I did this but the error still exists!

Comment: try this answer on stack overflow... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26771360/3678308